# Convolution of zero-padded DFT

Tags: convolution, fast-fourier-transform

I have a signal

$$x[0, \ldots , 2^n-1].$$ I would like to compute its DFT$$f[0, \ldots , 2^n-1],$$ take the first half $$f[0, \ldots , 2^{n-1}-1],$$ pad it with zeros,

$$g[i] = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}f[i] & \textrm{ if } i \in [0, \ldots , 2^{n-1}-1]\\
0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{array}\right., $$

and convolve that with some window $w$,

$$h = w \ast g.$$

Is there an easy way to use the DFT step to do the convolution for free? Of course I could $0$-pad $f$ and then do the convolution with two FFTs, for a total of three FFTs, but I'm wondering if I can get away with just one.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but this question is incomprehensible to me. What exactly are you asking? Is it to compute the DFT of x? Is it to do the convolution faster? Also, if $f$ is the DFT of $x$, then it should be a function of a continuous variable. Did you mean the DTFT? And what is the relationship between $g$ and $h$? Please clean this up if you expect some reasonable answer.

Comment: @StefanLafon the [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) is discrete in time **and** in frequency, and the [DTFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) is continuous in frequency. The goal is to compute $h$, defined as the result of the four-step process described in the question, in a fast way. Here, "fast" means computing the last convolution ($\mathcal{O}(N^2)$) using an FFT and an IFFT ($\mathcal{O}(N\log N)$). But this requires two FFTs and one IFFT, and OP asks if there is a way to combine those such that only one FFT is needed.

Comment: That's exactly right